# How to convert/working expo project on pc (windows)

Tags: android, react-native, expo

**Hello, i have project on expo that i get from github.
and i want work with andriod emulator (from android studio), and i don’t know how to do this.
in the project no have node_modules directory and not android directory .
very thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the right answer!**

Need to:

1. Install XDE Expo.
2. Run npm install on project directory.
3. Run android studio and emulator.
4. Run on XDE Expo -> Device -> Open on android.

Answer (score 0):

Create react-native project and then include the expo project files into that project and then run it on Android emulator